# How to enable wireless in a Fujitsu LH532?

Tags: networking

I have a **Fujitsu LH532** and when I installed ubuntu, the network menu didn't have "*connect to hidden network*" option nor "*create a new network*". I am not sure how to check my wireless card since when I enter `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` in the terminal nothing happens except it opens a new line.

Result was:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
```

Comment: We know it's not a Broadcom! Please edit your question to add the result of: lspci -nn | grep 0280. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download RT3290 PCIe here:  http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501 Right-click it and rename it from 2012_RT3290.xx.bz2 to 2012_RT3290.xx.*tar*.bz2. Then right-click it and select Extract Here. Open the folder that is created and go to os/linux and open the file config.mk with a text editor. Change HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n to HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y. Save and close the text editor. Now, with a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd Desktop/2012_RT3
```

Press Tab and the remainder will fill in automatically. Press Enter. Then do:

```
make
make install
modprobe rt3290sta
exit
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I got up to the build essential code but it displays this :  root@leo-LIFEBOOK-LH532:/home/leo# cd Desktop/2012_RT3
bash: cd: Desktop/2012_RT3: No such file or directory

Comment: In order for the rest of the lengthy name to fill in correctly, press Tab. After it is filled in, press Enter.

Comment: Apologies to bug you again but new problem :/ = root@leo-LIFEBOOK-LH532:/home/leo# cd Downloads/2012_RT3290.xx.tar.bz2 
bash: cd: Downloads/2012_RT3290.xx.tar.bz2: Not a directory

Comment: You missed a step up there: Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Then proceed.