# Unable to either locate any wireless networks nor even connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I'm new to Linux. I currently have installed ubuntu 12.10. I had a previous problem with my wireless card (see url to see previous problem : [How to enable wireless in a Fujitsu LH532?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224081/how-to-enable-wireless-in-a-fujitsu-lh532)). It now shows *Connect to hidden network* and *create new wireless network* but now unfortunately it simply cannot find any wireless connections. I did have a very thorough look around about this problem such as *wait a little longer since sometimes it cannot load all the wireless connections available that quickly*. My wifi is a hidden network and I have used the connect to hidden network feature but it keeps asking for my wep key which has been checked 4 times (I counted) and it still seems to not work; It keeps asking for the WEP key. I did try both WEP 40/128-bit key and WPA & WPA2 since previously on my windows it worked; My family later decided to use WEP.
I only have a quick fix using a usb wireless stick and I wish to have a more solid fix.

Thanks

Results from sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:1E:73:C8:62:BD
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"EnigmaHome"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000cb3bb10a5c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 696ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A456E69676D61486F6D65
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 0706484B20010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: C8:3A:35:34:C1:60
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Tenda"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001336e70ffdd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 716ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000554656E6461
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706434E20010D10
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: DD270050F204104A0001101044000101104700102880288028801880A880C83A3534C160103C000101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC0117FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05010089127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C33EC0117FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3406000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
          Cell 03 - Address: 00:1E:73:C8:62:BF
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000cb3bac614e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1064ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00110000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050C010200000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706484B20010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD070050F202000100
```

Comment: Do you have a wireless interface in iwconfig? If it is wlan0, does it scan and see networks? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan.

Answer (score 1):

I modified this to work in 12.10

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850267

However, I'm currently getting a kernel panic when I go to google or any other website

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the achitechture of the laptop you have but try installing the wifi proprietory drivers if it's an older system you may need legacy drivers

Comment: According to the question he linked, I believe he has installed the correct driver already.